# How to get text that has an ending nowrap to fit snug in my container

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the gray box to fill up as far as to where "long" ends, so that all that text could be centered. Having a fixed width won't work as the text within .child can change.

*Edit:* Would love to keep it looking like a sentence. As if there were more text after the hyperlink, I would want it to continue flowing like a sentence.

[image]

Below is what i hope it would be

[image]

Here's a link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jonyeezs/pen/ExmamVL)

```html
<style>

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  margin: 16px;
}

.child {
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">This is a sentence that is long <a href="#">Click here</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*I've a feeling what I am hoping is impossible due to how nowrap works.*

Comment: You can simply add `display:block` to the `a`-Element to get that effect, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jonyeezs can you clarify if you can add `display:block` to `a` or not?

Comment: @Nilanshu96  unfortunately that won't work. Maybe i didn't make it clear that it is a sentence. So if i added more text after the hyperlink, i don't want it to break into a new line.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

A way of achieving the desired result, would be by using flexbox on the child element like this:

```css
.child {
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Wrap your text "This is a sentence that is long" in a p element inside the **child** div like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
          <p>This is a sentence that is long</p>
          <a href="#">Click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And since p is a block element, the child div will not span longer than the text inside. All you will have to do, is to override the default margins of the p element in order to get de desired result.

Comment: I would like to keep it as a sentence and not break up the code

Answer (score -1):

Yow bro, just change the a tag to display block.
I already did it in yow code from

a {
white-space: nowrap;
}

To

a {
display: block
}

Comment: hey my man, i clarified what i envision...display block won't cut it yo. i aint want other text to flow to the next line